# check correct email format for swedish letters

Tags: php, forms, validation

i'm making a website that has a form which gets validated in php.
When people post the form the email gets sent to a $email variable and i check for the correct format. However i've yet to find a piece of code that checks if the format is correct (if its valid doesnt matter right now), i've found phps own function but it doesnt check for swedish letters, i've also found another function that checks the mail format but that breaks if you have an email with format xxx.yy@zz.aa. it only works if the format is xxx@zz.aa.

I would very much appreciate any help to make this work and to find a function that works.

Comment: do you need the swedish characters: here@orHere.se? or both

Comment: It should check for the correct syntax and be able to handle swedish letters aswell as english

Comment: this is something my solution below does!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this regexp:

```
 if(preg_match("/^\b[A-ZÅÄÖåäö0-9._%+-]+@[A-ZÅÄÖåäö0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i",$email)){
      //mail is valid
 }
```

This will validate youråäö@adressö.se etc.

Comment: and what about contact@best.company and other national domains? The problem with Swedish letter is not about Swedish letters only

Comment: And what do you think is the problem with the above solution?

Comment: \.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$ doesn't allow all bunch of new domains like .company, .coffee, ..construction and others. Russian, Japanese, and national zones like .移动 and .РФ

Comment: if you really need that you can change the range to {2}. But will match all BIG top domains.

Answer (score -1):

Single thing that you can check in email address is it contains @. Check for that without any code found anywhere

Answer (score -2):

i personally suggest you to validate forms in client side (i.e) using javascript or jquery
if all form validations are carried to the server the server load gets increased that too there is re- submission for invalid entries.

jquery code for email validation :

```
function ValidateEmail(email) {
    var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    return expr.test(email);
};

$("#id").blur(function(){

    if(!ValidateEmail($("#id").val())){
        //your code
    }
    else {
        //your code
    }   
})
```

Comment: You should never trust the end user. Validating client side could be good to help user correct misstyped entries. But you should ALWAYS validate server side aswell!